# Fail to rewrite list with app_removelast_last

Tags: coq

I have an environment which looks like this:

```
P: list nat -> Prop
Hnil: P []
...
xs, xp: list nat
Hex: xp = a :: xs
Hnilcons: xp <> []
===================
P xp
```

I'd like to rewrite the goal to

```
P ((removelast xp)++[last xp 0])
```

As I have in the context a proof that xp in not nil, I try to use app_removelast_last:

```
Lemma app_removelast_last :
    forall l d, l <> [] -> l = removelast l ++ [last l d].
```

But when I try

```
rewrite (app_removelast_last xp 0 Hnilcons).
```

I get an obscure error message :

```
The term "Hnilcons" has type
 "not (@eq (list nat) xp (@nil nat))"
while it is expected to have type
 "not
    (@eq (list (list nat)) ?l
       (@nil (list nat)))"
(cannot unify "list (list nat)" and
"list nat").
```

Obviously, I don't understand how to use the proof that the list is not [].

Can someone help me clarify how to do this rewrite ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

The arguments you provided aren't the ones `app_removelast_last` expects. You can find this with `About`:

```
About app_removelast_last.
(*
app_removelast_last :
forall [A : Type] [l : list A] (d : A),
l <> [] -> l = removelast l ++ [last l d]

app_removelast_last is not universe polymorphic
Arguments app_removelast_last [A]%type_scope [l]%list_scope d _
*)
```

Arguments that appear inside square brackets (or curly braces, although here there are none) are [implicit](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/extensions/implicit-arguments.html). This means that Coq can infer them from the explicit arguments. So even though `app_removelast_last` needs four arguments to reach the equality (namely, `A`, `l`, `d`, and a proof of `l <> []`), it only expects two of them (`d` and a proof of `l <> []`), because `A` and `l` can be inferred from those. Or in other words, once you provide `d` and a proof of `l <> []`, there is only one possible choice for `A` and `l`.

Note that `d` is supposed to be a default value fed to `last` in case the list is empty. Here we know that the list is non-empty, so it is completely irrelevant which default value we pick, but we still must pick one. When you write `app_removelast_last xp Hnilcons`, you're saying that you want `xp` to be the default value (remember, `l` is implicit!). Then Coq infers that, since your default value has type `list nat`, the relevant `l` must have type `list (list nat)`, which is why you get that error message in particular.

The solution is to rewrite with, for example, `app_removelast_last 0 Hnilcons`, since `0` is an adequate default value.

---

Edit: You may also avoid implicit arguments with `@` as follows:

```
@app_removelast_last nat xp 0 Hnilcons
```

However, according to your comment you are not using the stdlib's version of this lemma, but `Constant AlphaCode1_forward_c.app_removelast_last`, which apparently is specific to lists of natural numbers and has no implicit arguments, so this is probably not what's causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I use About on app_removelast_last, I have the following : app_removelast_last :
forall (l : list nat) (d : nat), l <> [] -> l = removelast l ++ [last l d]

app_removelast_last is not universe polymorphic
Arguments app_removelast_last l%list_scope d%nat_scope _
app_removelast_last is opaque
Expands to: Constant AlphaCode1_forward_c.app_removelast_last
So I still don't undestand what goes wrong...

Comment: Then something is weird and I cannot predict what it is without your full context. @FH35 , please edit your answer to include the needed context to reproduce that error message, including Coq version.

Comment: Maybe a way to answer without more information about the implicit arguments of remove_last is to force all explicit arguments using `@`.